# Div tag issue for setting the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue related with div tag height settings. As I am developing product for desktop and laptop.

Currently implemented `<div class="matter" id="matter" style="height:74vh;">`
but size of footer is overlapped with this `div`.

I also tried to set the `max-height` but it wont be possible to set in percentage.
So, any solution regarding this query is welcome...

Comment: post some code, we can't assume that.

Comment: This is a very ambiguous question, add some code, perhaps demonstrate your issue with a jsfiddle.net

Comment: height should be in em or px? (not vh)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to consider using some responsive css framework such as bootstrap or foundation to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It makes the layout for web design easier and the most important thing is it is responsive.